# Flex Validator -- Show Red Error Border on DataGrid Cell

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I can successfully add a validator on an item in my datagrid, by passing in the particular element in the dataProvider to the validator, but I can't get the red border to show up around the cell if the validation fails.

I have stepped through the validator,  and confirmed that it is passing back a failure, but I can't figure out why the red error border doesn't show up. I have a feeling its because I am passing the item in my dataProvider as the validator source, rather than the 'cell' item, but I can't find a way to access the cell.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `showFocusrect=true`?

Comment: I don't see an option to apply that on the DataGrid or on the DataGridColumn

Answer (score 0):

If you use an AdvancedDataGrid, there is a styleFunction you can specify that might suit your needs.  You can put logic in the function specified to change various attributes of the cell.